# Decrypt a file in php which is encrypted in android

Tags: php, android, wampserver

I encrypted a file in android using triple des. This file is uploaded to the server using php. Have to write php script to decrypt the same file.

New to php, any help would be appreciated with php scripts.

```
public void encrypt(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws Exception {
    final SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "DESede");
    final IvParameterSpec param = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
    final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, param);

    // Read in the cleartext bytes and write to out to encrypt
    int numRead = 0;
    while ((numRead = in.read(buf)) >= 0) {
        byte[] output = cipher.doFinal(buf, 0, numRead);
        if(output != null) {
            byte[] enc = Base64.encode(output, 0);
            out.write(enc);
        }   
    }
    out.close();
}
```

I'm passing hard coded values for `keyBytes` and `iv` which are hexadecimal values.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/), and [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it seems like you are going to have to use the mcrypt extension. The mcrypt extension supports TRIPLEDES.

**[Installation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.setup.php)**

[List](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.ciphers.php) of ciphers supported by mcrypt.

Here are some mcrypt [examples](http://php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.examples.php).

The mcrypt function to decrypt is [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-decrypt.php).

I'm currently learning android and advanced php. If you are new to php, I highly recommend going to php.net for everything. It's been very helpful for me.

Comment: I saw the links you mentioned. Do i have to install the mcrypt extension in my server? i'm using WAMP server.

Comment: Read my updated answer. I know I did not provide you with the direct answer, but it's easier to direct you to the answer.

Let me know if this was the solution to your problem. If it was, please hit the check mark by my answer for future programmers with this problem.

Comment: I followed the installation link. But in my wamp server there is no such dll. So, i downloaded the dll's and restarted the service. But, i get errors like this  mcrypt_decrypt(): Module initialization failed. Help me with this please!

Comment: Did you run these two commands:
`sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt`
`sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

Also, did you read the comments here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.setup.php

It looks like people are having the same problem.